# Function power C++

Tags: c++

I need to write need a function to compute `power` in C++

I don't understand why my code below is wrong.

ex. :  base: 2  exponent 3 -> result: 4.48498e-306
if i use "int" the result is -> 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double power(double base, double exponent);       

int main()
{    
    double base, exponent, power;

    cout << "Enter a base " << endl;
    cin >> base;
    cout << "Enter an exponent" << endl;
    cin >> exponent;
    cout << "The result is ': "<< power << endl;
    return 0;
}    

double power(double base, double exponent)
{
    int i;
    double s=1;
    for (i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
        s *= base;
    return s;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error; I get 8.

Comment: uhmm... you never call the function...

Comment: other than that, make exponente int and all is good.

Comment: Did you even BOTHER to try to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either printing the address of the function `power` or printing the uninitialized value of the double `power` the way you have written the code.  (Technically you are hitting an uninitialized shadowed variable).  In any case, you are not even calling the function you wrote... How does the `power` function know to be called? With what arguments?

Fix 1. Suggest you delete the 'double' of `power`.
Fix 2. Actually call the function and use/store/print the result

example. 
After getting input from user do this:

```
double result = power( base, exponent );
cout << result << endl;
```

To print the result.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have two declarations of `power`.

`double power(double base, double esponente);`

`double base,esponente,power;`

You declare the variable `power` but you never initialize it before printing it, so it's going to be undefined. Rerunning your program will actually give you a different number, in all likelihood. You need to remove this local variable declaration, as it shadows the global function declaration.

Then, instead of

`cout<<"\nL'elevamento a potenza e': "<<power<<endl;`

You want this line:

`cout<<"\nL'elevamento a potenza e': "<<power(base, esponente)<<endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You need call function like this, with parameters:
Here is your main. You don't need local variable power. You want call function with name power.

```
int main ()
{    
 double base,esponente;    
 cout<<" \n Inserisci base \n";
 cin>>base;
 cout<<"\nInserisci esponente\n";
 cin>>esponente;                                                   
 cout<<"\nL'elevamento a potenza e': "<<power(base,esponente)<<endl;
 system ("PAUSE");                                     
}
```

Comment: tell him to remove the local variable `power`